# LINUX: How to output tables used in SQL script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, grep

people.

I have a ton of SQL scripts (1000+ files), and I have to list some information about them. The main problem is to list all tables, and operations being used, on each script. I need to find mainly SELECT, INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE operations.

**SELECT EXAMPLE:**

```
     SELECT column1, column2
       FROM SCHEMA1.TABLE_A A, SCHEMA1.TABLE_B B,
            SCHEMA3.TABLE_K, SCHEMA3.TABLE_M,
            SCHEMA4.TABLE N
      INNER JOIN SCHEMA2.TABLE_C C ON C.COLUMN_XX = A.COLUMN_XX
       LEFT JOIN SCHEMA2.TABLE_D D ON D.COLUMN_YY = A.COLUMN_YY
 FULL OUTER JOIN SCHEMA2.TABLE_E E ON E.COLUMN_ZZ = B.COLUMN_ZZ
      WHERE B.COLUMN_AA = A.COLUMN_AA
        AND K.COLUMN_KK = A.COLUMN_KK
        AND M.COLUMN_MM = A.COLUMN_MM
        AND N.COLUMN_NN = A.COLUMN_NN;
```

**OUTPUT FOR SELECT WOULD BE (ORDER DOESNT MATTER):**

```
SCHEMA1.TABLE_A | SELECT
SCHEMA1.TABLE_B | SELECT
SCHEMA3.TABLE_K | SELECT
SCHEMA3.TABLE_M | SELECT
SCHEMA4.TABLE_N | SELECT
SCHEMA2.TABLE_C | SELECT
SCHEMA2.TABLE_D | SELECT
SCHEMA2.TABLE_E | SELECT
```

**INSERT EXAMPLE:**

```
INSERT INTO SCHEMA1.TABLE_A (COLUMN1,COLUMN2) VALUES ('VALUE_1','VALUE_2');
INSERT INTO SCHEMA1.TABLE_B
(COLUMN_1,COLUMN2)
VALUES
('VALUE_1','VALUE_2');
INSERT INTO SCHEMA2.TABLE_C SELECT * FROM SCHEMA5.TABLE_C;
```

**OUTPUT FOR INSERT WOULD BE (ORDER DOESNT MATTER):**

```
SCHEMA1.TABLE_A | INSERT
SCHEMA1.TABLE_B | INSERT
SCHEMA2.TABLE_C | INSERT
SCHEMA5.TABLE_C | SELECT (IF IT IS "OK" TO PUT SOMETHING LIKE 'SELECT (INSERT)' WOULD BE BETTER.. IF NOT, THAT'S OK)
```

**DELETE EXAMPLE:**

```
DELETE FROM SCHEMA3.TABLE_K WHERE K.COLUMN_KK = 'A';
DELETE FROM SCHEMA1.TABLE_A A
 INNER JOIN SCHEMA2.TABLE_C C ON C.COLUMN_XX = A.COLUMN_XX
 WHERE A.COLUMN_AA = 'A';
```

**OUTPUT FOR DELETE WOULD BE (ORDER DOESNT MATTER):**

```
SCHEMA3.TABLE_K | DELETE
SCHEMA1.TABLE_A | DELETE
SCHEMA2.TABLE_C | JOIN (IF IT IS "OK" TO PUT SOMETHING LIKE 'JOIN (DELETE)' WOULD BE BETTER... IF NOT, THAT'S OK)
```

**UPDATE EXAMPLE:**

```
UPDATE SCHEMA1.TABLE_A SET COLUMN_AA = 'A';
UPDATE SCHEMA2.TABLE_C SET COLUMN_CC = (SELECT COLUMN_CC FROM SCHEMA5.TABLE_C)
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SCHEMA5.TABLE_C C2 WHERE C2.COLUMN_CC = C.COLUMN_CC);
UPDATE SCHEMA2.TABLE_D D
 INNER JOIN SCHEMA1.TABLE_A A ON D.COLUMN_ID = A.COLUMN_ID
   SET D.COLUMN_DD = A.COLUMN_DD;
```

**OUTPUT FOR UPDATE WOULD BE (ORDER DOESNT MATTER):**

```
SCHEMA1.TABLE_A | UPDATE
SCHEMA2.TABLE_C | UPDATE
SCHEMA5.TABLE_C | SELECT
SCHEMA2.TABLE_D | UPDATE
SCHEMA1.TABLE_A | JOIN (IF IT IS "OK" TO PUT SOMETHING LIKE 'JOIN (UPDATE)' WOULD BE BETTER... IF NOT, THAT'S OK)
```

Any clues about which utility is the best to do it, how to overcome main problems, like line breaks after FROM, like how to get words after one specific work (like how to get what is after FROM clause), how to identify the main operation on the JOIN clauses, etc, would be most welcome.

Thank you ALL.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm this is quite tough to interpret all SQL syntax (PostgeSQL, Oracle, MS ..,) into regexps.

Anyway here is some initial example of AWK which should work for Your SELECT and INSERT statements examples:

```
awk '
BEGIN { RS="[ ,;\n]"; }
/^SELECT$|^INSERT$/ { operation=$1; watchtable=0; }
/^FROM$|^JOIN$|^INTO$/ { watchtable=1; }
/^WHERE$|^INNER$|^OUTER$|^LEFT$|^RIGHT$|^ON$|^ORDER$|^GROUP$|^\(/ { watchtable=0; }
watchtable && /^[^\.]+\.[^\.]+$/ { print($0 " | " operation); }
' SELECT.sql INSERT.sql
```

You can continue and tune up for further and more solid code.

Note: Per Your examples I made the task easier and assume that Your Tables are always in form schema.table.

Output for SELECT:

```
SCHEMA1.TABLE_A | SELECT
SCHEMA1.TABLE_B | SELECT
SCHEMA3.TABLE_K | SELECT
SCHEMA3.TABLE_M | SELECT
SCHEMA4.TABLE | SELECT
SCHEMA2.TABLE_C | SELECT
SCHEMA2.TABLE_D | SELECT
SCHEMA2.TABLE_E | SELECT
```

Output for INSERT:

```
SCHEMA1.TABLE_A | INSERT
SCHEMA1.TABLE_B | INSERT
SCHEMA2.TABLE_C | INSERT
SCHEMA5.TABLE_C | SELECT
```

Answer (score 0):

simple command for all operations :

```
cat your_sql_script.sql | tr -d "\n" | tr ";" "\n" | sed 's/$/;/'
```

Now you can grep any sql command .
this is output for your delete pasted :

```
DELETE FROM SCHEMA3.TABLE_K WHERE K.COLUMN_KK = 'A'
DELETE FROM SCHEMA1.TABLE_A A INNER JOIN SCHEMA2.TABLE_C C ON C.COLUMN_XX = A.COLUMN_XX WHERE A.COLUMN_AA = 'A'
```

Maybe this help you :

```
cat SELECT.sql | tr -d "\n" | tr ";" "\n" | sed 's/$/;/' | awk '{print $3,"|",$1}'
```

output :

```
SCHEMA3.TABLE_K | DELETE
SCHEMA1.TABLE_A | DELETE
```